# Definition for gapi in an Angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-drive-api

I'm trying to implement the Google Drive API into my AngularJS application.

Whenever I look at examples for access the API, I would often see something like `gapi.client.setApiKey( 'XXXX' );`
However when I try to use the gapi library I'm just running into the 'gapi' is not defined error.
And this is happening on the console on my computer, not the browser console.

So I'm just wondering if I'm missing some kind of dependency that isn't specified in the API docs?

Here is the example that I followed:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js#basic-ideas

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the html markup that loads the scripts? Or a jsfiddle?

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/pinoyyid/ngDrive

Comment: @pinoyyid that seem to be what I'm looking for. I'll see if this works, thanks a ton!

Comment: @pinoyyid if you have some time, can you look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386497/ngdrive-not-defined