# ngDrive not defined?

Tags: angularjs, git, google-drive-api

This question is a follow up to [Definition for gapi in an Angular controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376469/definition-for-gapi-in-an-angular-controller?noredirect=1#comment60385004_36376469) which is posted yesterday.

User pinoyyid pointed me to his git repo ngDrive (https://github.com/pinoyyid/ngDrive)

I was working through the quit start and ran into an error saying `'ngDrive' is not defined` in my console.

This was the code that cause this error

```
angular.module('ngm.ngDrive')
.provider('OauthService', ngDrive.Config)
.config(function (OauthServiceProvider) {
    OauthServiceProvider.setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file');
    OauthServiceProvider.setClientID('2231299-2bvf1.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    OauthServiceProvider.setTokenRefreshPolicy(ngDrive.TokenRefreshPolicy.ON_DEMAND);
    OauthServiceProvider.setNoAccessTokenPolicy(999);                 // 0 = fail, > 0 = retry after x
});
```

Specifically the `ngDrive.Config`

I had no issue when injecting the service into my `app.js` file as shown below

```
angular
 .module('App', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch',
'ui.sortable',
'firebase',
'angular-toArrayFilter',
'ngm.ngDrive'
])
```

I have also placed the script tag for the library as specified:

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="bower_components/ngDrive/build/module.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/login_controller.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/view_resources_ctrl.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here. I don't see anything in the guide that I might have accidentally skipped.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I did `bower install ngDrive --save`, included `<script src="../bower_components/ngDrive/build/module.js"></script>` (my index.js is in an app folder) before app.js, injected the `ngm.ngDrive`, copy-pasted the `.provider('OauthService', ngDrive.Config)`. Then I added into config,

```
OauthServiceProvider.setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file');
OauthServiceProvider.setClientID('2231299-2bvf1.apps.googleusercontent.com');
OauthServiceProvider.setTokenRefreshPolicy(ngDrive.TokenRefreshPolicy.ON_DEMAND);
OauthServiceProvider.setNoAccessTokenPolicy(999);
```

Nothing complained about `ngDrive.Config`. But I do get errors:

1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found): http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ngDrive/build/module.js.map (resource that I did not explicitly request for loading)
2. OauthServiceProvider.setNoAccessTokenPolicy is not a function. (In 'OauthServiceProvider.setNoAccessTokenPolicy(999)', 'OauthServiceProvider.setNoAccessTokenPolicy' is undefined). (checked the source and It seems this method does not exist in the current version of the module)

I tried but can't reproduce your error.

Comment: Would you mind putting your app.js file up on JsFiddle. I might just have something out of place that might be causing that error.

Comment: I made a JsFiddle of what my App.js and Index.html files look like https://jsfiddle.net/uoLpmaah/1/

Comment: See my main answer, the line `setNoAccessTokenPolicy ` should be deleted. I've fixed the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The `'ngDrive' is not defined` is caused by `module.js` failing to load. If you look at the network tab, you'll see a 404.

Also, there is a bug in the documentation, `setNoAccessTokenPolicy` is no longer a feature, so you should delete that line. Version 0.1.10 fixes the documentation.

Comment: The `'ngDrive' is not defined` error is not appearing in the browser console, it's appearing in my local command line when I put the code in and save it. http://puu.sh/o6QxM/5914b30903.png

Comment: that error is coming from jshint? If so you can just ignore it.